# Invalid date while formating using simple date format

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, sqldatetime

I have a date String `Mon Feb 8 00:00:00 UTC+0530 1954`. I want to convert it into the format `DD/MM/YYYY`. The output is always `08/38/1954 or 09/39/1954`.

I have used the following code.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY", Locale.US);
System.out.println(format.format(new Date(dateStr)));
```

Comment: Month first, as in the code sample?  Or day first, as in the second sentence of the question body?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`D` in `SimpleDateformat` stands for `day in year` where as `d` stands for `day in month` so replace `DD` with `dd`.

similary replace `YYYY` with `yyyy`

Answer (score 3):

`DD` in `SimpleDateFormat`is for the "Day in year", you want "Day in month", which is `dd`.

Also beware that `YYYY` is for "Week year", which depending on the calendar falls back to "Year", which is represented as `yyyy`. I suppose, you want `yyyy`anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the parse() method to go from a String date to the defined SimpleDateFormat.

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
 Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
 System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: This will output the current date in the given format. He specifically wants to output the given date, which needs to be parsed first.

Comment: He has a very specific input string, your's will try to match it against the format pattern.

Comment: by using the above code i am getting the parse exception. but when i create new date object and format i am getting the correct output. why it is getting parser exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.US);
Date dateStr = frmt.parse("Mon Feb 8 00:00:00 UTC+0530 1954");
```

Comment: My answer was really unnecessary, but I like to think in some regex solution to things like this. It's was like to redesign the wheel.